# Twitter Bootstrap ProgressBar with Badge on left and right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have a progressbar with left and right justified badges on either side that is centered within a row-fluid.

Similar to this:

[image]

Here is what I have so far which is not working.

```
<div class='row-fluid'>
   <div class="span12" style="">
      <span class="badge" style="position: relative;">X</span>
      <div class="progress" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto;width:50%;">
         <div class="bar" style="width:10%;"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="badge" style="position: relative;">0</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would `Prepend` and `Append` do anything? From [Forms](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms)

Comment: Could you use :before and :after CSS psuedo selectors?

Comment: @KyleMit I played around with the Prepend and Append but all that did was tack the badges on the top and bottom instead of the left and the right.

Comment: @michaellee The psuedo elements just add an invisible element before or after.  I can't picture how this could be helpful without an example.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the answer to [align twitter bootstrap progress bar and badge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10872265/1366033).

The problem is that the [progress bar](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.1.1/docs/components.html#progress) has to be put in a div, but div is a block element so it creates a line break between the elements around it.  To alter this behavior, you have to change the style of the things around it.

To get the left badge inline with the progress bar, either add `Class="pull-left"` or `Style="float: left;"` to the first badge.

To get the right badge inline, you have to make sure the progress bar doesn't take up the full width of the screen which will bump the second badge to the bottom.  For example, if all three items were inside a div with class `span8`, only make the progress bar have `span6`.

### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/nfkr5/)

```html
<div class="span8">
    <span class="badge pull-left">X</span>
    <div class="progress span6" >
        <div class="bar" style="width:10%;"></div>
    </div>
    <span class="badge">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not center correctly if it is within a row-fluid.  Also when inside a row-fluid, the progressbar height changes to 30px and I can't change it.  I updated the jsfiddle to show you what I mean.

Comment: Here is the fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/Mikt25/khQR2](http://jsfiddle.net/Mikt25/khQR2)

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution to my own question with the use of *gasp* a table…but it does keep the entire content centered, and doesn't change the height of the bar, etc.  If someone could post a non-table version I'd definitely accept that answer.

Here is the code:

```
<div class='row-fluid'>
    <div class="span12">
        <table style="width: 80%;margin:0 auto;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 15%;padding-right:3px;">
                    <span class="badge" style="float:right;">X:</span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 70%;">
                    <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
                        <div  id="xbar" class="bar" style="width: 50%;"></div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 15%;padding-left:3px;">
                    <span id="xval" class="badge" style="float:left;">0</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```